# How to instantiate a list using ADT interface

Tags: java

I am trying to trace some code from my textbook but whenever I try to complile it, I get a cannot find symbol error pointing to `AList<>()`.

```java
public static void recordWinners() {
    ListInterface<String> runnerList = new AList<>();

    runnerList.add("16"); // Winner
    runnerList.add(" 4"); // Second place
    runnerList.add("33"); // Third place
    runnerList.add("27"); // Fourth place
    displayList(runnerList); 
}
```

Could someone explain to me how I am supposed to instantiate this list?

Comment: The problem is that there is no AList defined or ListInterface is available in java just use normal declarations.(I am assuming you are using java here)